# dialog function error invalid function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, load

TypeError: $("").html("This dialog will show every time!").dialog is not a function

This is the error I'm getting. The page is loaded using load() in a div on the index page. I've included the necessary jquery stuff on the index page (which I'd prefer to keep that way), the loaded page, and both, and it still does this. I'm not sure exactly what's up. I know it's more difficult working with a load() page instead of just the page itself, but even going to the page home.php, it still says it. Below is a link to the load page, if you want to see the index just take out home.php in the address.

[The page that is being loaded](http://hardcoregamesusa.com/home.php)

This is the function I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function readMore(id,title,cat,desc,post,auth) {
        //alert(id +","+ title +","+ cat +","+ desc +","+ post +","+ auth);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html('This dialog will show every time!').dialog({autoOpen: false,title: 'Basic Dialog'});
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        $dialog.title = title;
        $dialog.html(desc);
    }
    </script>
```

As it is right now, all the includes for dialog are on the load page, and not the index page, but like I said, I've tried one or the other or both, to no avail. Also alert works fine and is passing everything correctly and is getting called when I want it to. All the paths to the jquery includes are correct.

And if it helps narrow it down for some reason, I'm getting theres errors on page load too:
TypeError: $.widget is not a function
[Break On This Error]

```
_uiHash: function(event) {
```

jquery...able.js (line 504)

TypeError: $.widget is not a function
[Break On This Error]

```
_mouseCapture: function(event) { return true; }
```

jquery...ouse.js (line 162)

TypeError: $.widget is not a function
[Break On This Error]

```
ui: function() {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need:

- jquery.ui.button.js
- jquery.ui.dialog.js

Also put mouse before draggable, as  commented above by Musa, it's important.

summary:

1. jquery.ui.core.js
2. jquery.ui.widget.js
3. jquery.ui.mouse.js
4. jquery.ui.position.js
5. jquery.ui.draggable.js
6. jquery.ui.resizable.js
7. jquery.ui.button.js
8. jquery.ui.dialog.js

But instead of loading all the single files I would suggest to load the complete UI from a CDN.

```
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: lol. I imagine I need just the dialog css too? Or is there more to it? And just to add; I feel pretty stupid because it's obvious I needed those js files, but it actually doesn't say it, at least as I saw, for a requirement on their demo page for the modual.

Comment: The CSS also would be fine when you want a styled dialog^^

Comment: How/what do you do the complete UI from CDN? I'm still pretty new to javascript in general, especially jquery.

Comment: I've added the code above, it's all you need when you want to use jQuery(including UI).

Comment: And that's all the includes I need for all of jquery for anything?

Comment: Exactly, and you may assume that it's already inside the browser-cache of your most visitors before they visit your page.

Comment: Lol sorry just making sure. I appreciate it. Guess I should read more, that's a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

`jquery.ui.mouse`, `jquery.ui.draggable` and `jquery.ui.resizable` needs to come after `jquery.ui.widget` because they call `.widget()`, also widget uses position so put it bfore like.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still getting these errors:

TypeError: base is not a constructor
[Break On This Error]  

var basePrototype = new base();

jquery...dget.js (line 67)

TypeError: $("<div></div>").html("This dialog will show every time!").dialog is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

...v></div>').html('This dialog will show every time!').dialog({autoOpen: false,tit...

Comment: @GrantKesslerJr you've removed the scripts from the site so I can't see what's wrong, but I think this is the order of the files `position`->`widget`->`mouse`->`draggable`->`resizeable`.

Comment: I attempted to put them on index page, I'll add them back to home.php instead, but I was hopeing to keep them on the parent page instead, as jquery already loads there. They're on home.php again.

Comment: @GrantKesslerJr put `mouse` before `draggable`

Comment: I appreciate the help, as this removed every single extra error I was getting outside of the dialog stuff.